# How to delete a specified number of columns based on the last column using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Sub BlaBla()
Dim LastCol As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Columns(LastCol).Delete
End With
End Sub
```

When I run the Macro, the last column is deleted. However, I want to delete say, 5 columns starting from the last, rather than one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - 4), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
```

Or you can declare a `Constant Variable` to hold the number of columns to be deleted which you can change if required.

```
Const DelCnt As Integer = 5
Sub BlaBla()
Dim LastCol As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

If you want to control the number of columns to be deleted from a cell on the sheet, you can follow this approach...

```
Sub BlaBla()
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim DelCnt As Integer
DelCnt = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E18").Value
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= DelCnt Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that performs the function very well. Howver, I wanted to know whether it is possible to state  LastCol - Value, where Value is the exact number of the columns which will be deleted. At the current moment, -1, removes two columns, rather than 1.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: I have added another solution, please see if that takes care of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to work very well! Would I be able to adjust the Constant variable from another worksheet? For example would this be feasible? Const DelCnt As Integer Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E18"), or it should really stay constant and I cant vary it through Sheet2?

Comment: It's a constant variable and you have to initialize it while declaring it and you cannot change it during run time. If you want to control this variable from a cell on any sheet in the workbook, you don't need to declare it as a constant variable, all you need is to declare it as `Dim DelCnt as Integer` and then initialize it like `DelCnt = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E18").Value`, considering `E18` on `Sheet2` controls the number of columns to be deleted.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added the above suggested approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to present...

```
Sub DeleteLast5()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        With .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
            If .Column > 5 Then
                .Offset(0, -4).Resize(, 5).Delete
            Else
                .Columns("A:E").Delete
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K thanks.  I was getting inco sistent results with `.Columns("A:E").Delete` but I'm sure that it is right.

Comment: Yeah, AFAIK the `Columns("A:E").Delete` part should be fine.